# Which encoding to use while reading Excel using xlrd

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, xlrd, latin1

I am trying to read an Excel file using xlrd to write into txt files. Everything is being written fine except for some rows which has some spanish characters like 'Téd'. I can encode those using latin-1 encoding. However the code then fails for other rows which have a 'â' with unicode u'\u2013'. u'\2013' can't be encoded using latin-1. When using UTF-8 'â' are written out fine but 'Téd' is written as 'TÃ©d' which is not acceptable. How do I correct this.

Code below :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd
import csv
import sys

filePath     = sys.argv[1]

with xlrd.open_workbook(filePath) as wb:
     shNames = wb.sheet_names()
     for shName in shNames:
         sh = wb.sheet_by_name(shName)
         csvFile = shName + ".csv"
         with open(csvFile, 'wb') as f:
              c = csv.writer(f)
              for row in range(sh.nrows):
                  sh_row = []
                  cell = ''
                  for item in sh.row_values(row):
                      if isinstance(item, float):
                         cell=item
                      else:
                         cell=item.encode('utf-8')
                      sh_row.append(cell)
                      cell=''
                  c.writerow(sh_row)
         print shName + ".csv File Created"
```

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Python's `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

> doesn’t support Unicode input.

You are correctly encoding your input before writing it -- so you don't need `codecs`. Just `open(csvFile, "wb")` (the `b` is important) and pass that object to the writer:

```
with open(csvFile, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([entry.encode("utf-8") for entry in row])
```

Alternatively, [`unicodecsv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.0) is a drop-in replacement for `csv` that handles encoding.

---

You are getting `Ã©` instead of `é` because [you are mistaking UTF-8 encoded text for latin-1](http://www.weblogism.com/item/270/why-does-e-become-a). This is probably because you're encoding twice, once as `.encode("utf-8")` and once as `codecs.open`.

---

By the way, the right way to check the type of an `xlrd` cell is to do `cell.ctype == xlrd.ONE_OF_THE_TYPES`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But, which encoding do I use? Or is there no other way than using unicodecsv?

Comment: Removed the codecs from codecs.open and tried again. Same problem!

Comment: @katrielalex how to deal with for example such errors while using your method?: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: You're trying to encode a float (i.e. a decimal number). You have to `str` it first.